# What is the best place to insert "implements Xyz"? Abstract vs. extending class

Tags: java, multithreading, abstract-class

Let us assume we have a abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Foo {
  public Foo (boolean bar) {...}
}
```

We also have a class that extends `Foo`:

```
public class FooThread extends Foo {}
```

As the name says, `FooThread` will be a Thread and thereby should implement Runnable.

The question is: What is the best place for `implements Runnable` in terms of extensibility and readability (or any other reason)?

Some alternatives might be:

1) Insert `implements` into the abstract class:

```
public abstract class Foo implements Runnable {}
```

- Easy to understand when looking at the abstract class
- Less extensible

2) Insert `implements` into the extending class:

```
public class FooThread extends Foo implements Runnable {}
```

- No hint on Thread functionality in the abstract class
- More extensible

3) Insert `implements` into the extending class and add `run()` as an abstract method to the abstract class:

```
public class FooThread extends Foo implements Runnable {}

public abstract class Foo {
  public Foo (boolean bar) {...}
  public abstract void run();
}
```

- Readability when looking at the abstract class
- Extensible (well, at least a little more flexible)
- The abstract method in the abstract class is sort of redundant
- "Ugly"

Is there a best practice for placing the `implements Runnable` or `implements Xyz` in general? At the earliest point or in the class that really implements the interface? Or does it really depend on what we want? What would you prefer?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Depends, is `Foo` runnable? One says I have a class that `extends Foo` and also adds runnable functionality. The other says that any class that `extends Foo` **must** add runnable functionality.

Comment: What is stopping you doing both?

Comment: BTW, this is a bit off topic, but if your class is not an actual Thread, then don't name it "FooThread". It is confusing as the term "thread" already has a definite meaning in Java. "FooTask" might be better.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : You are right. I really have to think about the properties of `Foo` a little more. @Torben : Thank you, you have a good point there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put it at the first place it becomes a *requirement*. Don't force things to be `Runnable` if they don't need to be. If they *need* to be `Runnable` then add the interface.

So, in this case, I would plump for your option (2): put `implements Runnable` on the `FooThread` class and not on the `Foo` abstract class unless all subclasses of `Foo` are required to be runnable as threads (but its name does not suggest that to be the case).

Similarly, you don't need to add `public abstract void run()`, as per your option (3), unless all `Foo` implementations *must* have that method; and if that's the case, you can simply implement `Runnable` instead, as per your option (1).

I agree with Torben that `FooThread` would be better named as `FooTask`. Not just because a Runnable is not a Thread (a Thread is a Runnable, but not vice versa) but also because the word "Task" is more business domain oriented (a higher level of abstraction).

Answer (score 1):

If *all instances* of your abstract class are supposed to be used as runnable tasks, then make the abstract class implement Runnable interface.

Otherwise don't implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it depends on who's going to be the runnable:

- the whole hierarchy -> abstract class
- only some implementations -> only required implementations

Regarding `implements xyz` the question is similar:

- do they have something in common that you could put together in the base abstract class -> abstract class + [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)
- must all of them implement that exact functionality and it is completely different in each -> abstract class
- only some of them -> required only